# c# ora-01017 invalid username/password

Tags: c#, database, oracle, database-connection

I have read a few other posts and not quite seem right as i don't have access to the server nor as an admin i am simply a user with a workspace i can create tables and such in my work space and i know it is possible to remotely connect but im not having any luck.

The error i get is ORA-01017: Invalid username/password; login denied.

[image: Error]

My code is:

```
static void Connect()
{
    con = new OracleConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
                                          + "(ADDRESS="
                                              +" (PROTOCOL=TCP)"
                                              +" (HOST=**host**)"
                                              +" (PORT=**port**))"
                                          +" (CONNECT_DATA="
                                              +" (SID=**sid**)))"
                                          +"User Id=MATTHEWFARRELL;"
                                          +"Password=PASSWORD;";
    con.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle \n\n" + con.ServerVersion);
}
```

Worse of all i did actually test this with a full uppercase password set to 'PASSWORD' but it was not set that for long.

I have tried:-

- setting everything to uppercase
- checking the format i am sending the data i tried adding ' ' around
  my user/pass this was not liked
- i read about installing wireshark but while i could do this on my
  local system i cannot on the other side.
  -tried adding FIPSPolicy to false to the app config.

  ```
  <configuration>
  <runtime>
  <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
  </runtime>
  </configuration>
  ```

Comment: Whatever else may be wrong, I think you at least need a semi-colon between the end of the `Data Source` and the `User Id`.  I.e., +" (SID=**sid**)));"+"User Id=MATTHEWFARRELL;"

Comment: I'll review this see if it makes a difference but if it's running the login part of the code not sure if this is the issue

Comment: Matthew McPeak you were right, that one minor thing changed everything, i noticed the use of the semi colon throughout the project changed a few behaviors in this case i should of included it i dont work with database connections much so small errors go unnoticed thank god for the internet.